# Search number of times a string occurs in text file

Tags: string, vbscript

I am trying to go read a text file and count the number of times a phrase/string (not word) occurs in the text file, but so far what I have is this:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\VBscript project\testing.txt", ForReading)
strContents = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

i = 0

arrLines = Split(strContents, "")

For Each strLine in arrLines
    If InStr(strLine, "hi there") Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo "Number of times word occurs: " & i
```

This will only allow me to count the number of times a word occurs, which does not work when I try to tweak it to count phrases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the below example:

```
strPath = "D:\VBscript project\testing.txt"
strPhrase = "hi there"

strContent = ReadTextFile(strPath, 0)
arrContent = Split(strContent, strPhrase)

MsgBox "Number of times phrase occurs: " & UBound(arrContent)

Function ReadTextFile(strPath, lngFormat)
    ' lngFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strPath, 1, False, lngFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

Note that `Split`-based method is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

```
strPath = "D:\VBscript project\testing.txt"
strPhrase = "hi there"

strContent = ReadTextFile(strPath, 0)
arrContent = Split(strContent, strPhrase)

MsgBox "Number of times phrase occurs: " & UBound(arrContent)

Function ReadTextFile(strPath, lngFormat)
    ' lngFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strPath, 1, False, lngFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly and what you are asking for is really as simple as it looks, you could just change the `"hi there"` string to a parameter. This way you can dynamically tell your function what to look for.

EDIT: Thanks to @omegastripes I noticed a flaw in my previous code, so this is one that would work.

The code would be like this:

```
Sub yourSubName (pstrTextToCount)
    Const ForReading = 1
    Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim objFile : Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\VBscript project\testing.txt", ForReading)
    Dim strContents : strContents = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close

    ' You don't need these objects anymore, so release them
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    Dim intTextPosition : intTextPosition = 0
    Dim i : i = -1
    Do
      i = i + 1
      intTextPosition = InStr(intTextPosition + 1, strContents, pstrTextToCount)
    Loop While (intTextPosition > 0)

    Wscript.Echo "Number of times '" & pstrTextToCount & "' occurs: " & i
End Sub
```

I am assuming your `Sub` will only do that and this is why I enclosed it into the `Sub`, `End Sub` statements. You can add any other coding that you need, but only remember to add your required parameter on the signature of the `Sub` for it to work.

PS: As a good practice, always `Dim` your variables and release memory of objects that are no longer needed with `Set objName = Nothing`

Comment: `Split(strContents, "")` is useless since it returns the only element.

Comment: Thanks @omegastripes, The delimiter should actually be `vbCrLf` there.

Comment: OK then, if one string contains `pstrTextToCount` text e. g. twice, will it count them up properly?

Comment: Actually...now that I come to think of...this wouldn't quite work if he have more than one occurrence of the text in the same line

Comment: I just hint not to split the entire text to separate lines;) And switch away from `InStr`.

Comment: My clue is to fix your answer to avoid unexpected downvotes.

Comment: @omegastripes, done. This now would work properly. Thanks again for the hint

Comment: Properly to a point. Both your and @omegastripes' approach only count phrases that appear on a single line. They'll skip over phrases that span more than one line (e.g. when there's a newline between two words). This scenario could be handled by replacing all whitespace with a single space before searching for matches.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers, I agree with you on that, but this might also depends on OP's intention. If he/she wants to consider the word count even if it there is a newline in between, then replacing the whitespaces would be required, but if he wants to count only for a specific wording sequence that occurs in the same line, I believe both answers will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Here a version using Regular Expressions so you can specify if the search needs to be case sensitive.
For testpurpose I use the contents of the script itself as input.

```
Dim path, phrase, content
path    = Wscript.ScriptFullName
phrase  = "hi there\^$*+?{}.()|[]"
content = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(path).ReadAll

Function NumberOfPhrasesInString(phrase, text, IgnoreCase)
  Dim regexpr, matches
  Set regexpr = New RegExp
  phrase = RegExEscape(phrase)
  With regexpr
    .Pattern = phrase
    .Global  = True
    .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
    Set matches = .Execute(text)
  End With
  NumberOfPhrasesInString = matches.count
End Function

Function RegExEscape(str)
  Dim special
  RegExEscape = str
  special = "\^$*+?{.()|[]"
  For i=1 To Len(special)
    RegExEscape = replace(RegExEscape, Mid(special, i, 1), "\" & Mid(special, i, 1))
  Next
End Function

Wscript.Echo "Number of times phrase occurs: " & NumberOfPhrasesInString(phrase, content, false)
```

As a bonus, since I'm switched to Ruby here also that version

```
path    = __FILE__ # the path to this script for test purposes
phrase  = 'HI THERE \ ^ $ * + ? { . ( | ['
puts phrase
content = File.read path

def number_of_phrases_in_string(phrase, text, ignoreCase=false )
  escaped = Regexp.escape(phrase)
  text.scan(Regexp.new(escaped, ignoreCase)).count.to_s 
end

puts "Number of times phrase occurs: " + number_of_phrases_in_string(phrase, content, true)
```

Or in a single line

```
puts File.read(__FILE__).scan(Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(phrase), true)).count
```

The true in the last line defines casesensitivity

Comment: Replace the line `phrase  = "hi there"` with `phrase  = "C:\Windows\System32"`

Comment: @omegastripes: this is a simple example, special characters need to be escaped, in Ruby that's with .escape, should have to do a search for Vbscript but shouldn't be a problem though

Comment: Currently appearing of `\ ^ $ * + ? { . ( | [` characters in the pattern will lead to unexpected result. IMO you should either fix the bug or point out this specific feature within your answer.

Comment: No problem, I edited all three versions to cope with special characters.
It shows once more the power of Ruby by keeping the code so terse while keeping readability.

Comment: Replace the line `phrase = "hi there\^$*+?{.()|[]"` with `phrase = "C:\Windows\System32"` in VBS version. BTW why did you use `"\\"`prefix for replacement?

Comment: @omegastripes: used the wrong source I guess, with one escape char it works, also with "C:\Windows\System32", thnx